# Split multiple values from a string in one column, into multiple columns using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, delimiter

I have a table in SQL server which outputs the following:

| CompanyName | CompanyNumber | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1st Comp Ltd | 1 | Credit broker;Limited Permission Lender;Insurance Intermediary |
| business.com | 456 | Investment Advisor;Credit Broking Only |
| Charity.org | 156789 | Not for profit |

I want to split the values in the tag column so that there is only one tag per column, so:

| CompanyName | CompanyNumber | Tag1 | Tag2 | Tag3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st Comp Ltd | 1 | Credit broker | Limited Permission Lender | Insurance Intermediary |
| business.com | 456 | Investment Advisor | Credit Broking Only |  |
| Charity.org | 156789 | Not for profit |  |  |

I can do this manually in excel using the semicolon as a delimiter, and then adjust the headers, but can this be done in SQL server? Ultimately I would like a view in SQL server to format the data so I can have a powershell script generate a csv and send in an email.

I've tried the following, I think I might be nearly there, it just doesn't work in a view:

```
with TagsDelimited_CTE AS
(select CompanyName, CompanyNumber, Value,
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CompanyName, CompanyNumber order by CompanyName, CompanyNumber) as RowNum
from  Source
CROSS APPLY
string_split(Tags,';') 
)
select CompanyName, CompanyNumber,
[1] as Tag1,
[2] as Tag2,
[3] as Tag3
From TagsDelimited_CTE
PIVOT
(MAX(value)
For RowNum in ([1],[2],[3])) as PVT
```

Any assistance would be a big help, thanks.

Comment: seems to work fine, also in a view

Comment: It now works for me as well, I must have made a mistake somewhere, apologies.

Comment: The table is not normalized. This is what makes working with it so hard. I suggest you change the database design (or have it changed), so it becomes a relational database as it is supposed to be, with a separate company_tag table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a bit of JSON  and assuming you have a known or maximum number of tags

```
Select A.CompanyName
      ,A.CompanyNumber
      ,Tag1  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]')
      ,Tag2  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')
      ,Tag3  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]')
From  YourTable A
Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(STRING_ESCAPE(Tags,'json'),';','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . You and JSON.  It's like dark magic.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to pivot inside an `APPLY`, because then you can do it per row.

Pivoting using `MAX(CASE` is also usually more flexible.

> Note that the ordering of the values are not guaranteed

```sql
SELECT
  s.CompanyName,
  s.CompanyNumber,
  v.*
FROM Source s
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Value END) AS Tag1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Value END) AS Tag2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Value END) AS Tag3      
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
        FROM STRING_SPLIT (s.Tags, ';') splitted
    ) v
) v;
```

Comment: Totally just FYI but I've started to use `ORDER BY @@SPID` (and `ORDER BY @@TRANCOUNT` if you want to force serial execution) instead of `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`. Some conversations about it with Paul White, Martin Smith, and Itzik BenGan [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/04/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-4), [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/05/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-5), and [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/11/t-sql-queries/row-numbers-with-nondeterministic-order).

Comment: Thanks, I did see that conversation when we were working on that series (I'm Charlie over there), but didn't see any benefit apart from shorter syntax. Looking over it again, the only benefit is that it allows a trivial plan, [Martin points that out](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/11/t-sql-queries/row-numbers-with-nondeterministic-order#comment-163256) Also I couldn't bear it if Erik had to rename [his website](https://orderbyselectnull.com) to https://orderbyspid.com, it just doesn't have the same ring :-)